# Is need to change DB in unit test cases - python django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am creating unit test cases now.. I create delete API.. Its working fine with Post Man. Its delete the the Record... But Its do not delete Report when I run this in test case.. Its wrong something or its normal behaviour in test cases. I am creating this test cases in python..

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: have you specified test database? if not django creates a dummy test database for running tests so it would not affect your data

Comment: for reference check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/overview/

Answer (score 0):

As i remember, you can add multiple connections in `settings.py` file

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
        'NAME': 'db_prod',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'http://example.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'test': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
        'NAME': 'db_test',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'http://example.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Then use it on model like this `Model.objects.using('test')`